# How do I parse a file with XML-like structure, but with self-closing tags next to content (instead of enclosing the content)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, xml-parsing, domparser

I have a file of the following structure. It's not XML, but I need to somehow make a JSON out of it.

So **while I would expect** the file to look like this:

```
<chapter>
<line> Some text which I want to grab. </line>
<line> Some more text which I want to grab. </line>
<line> Even more text which I want to grab. </line>
</chapter>
```

It is **in fact** structured like this:

```
<chapter>
<line /> Some text which I want to grab.
<line /> Some more text which I want to grab.
<line /> Even more text which I want to grab.
</chapter>
```

So the 'lines' of each chapter just stand next to the self-closing line tags. Can you recommend a method of grabbing these? Possibly in javascript / nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is valid XML, so you can use the regular XML techniques ... i.e `DOMParser`, to parse the content

However, you just need to be a bit clever about parsing the lines - you want to find each line, and  gather up all the sibling nodes that are text nodes (should be only one, but the code I present doesn't make any assumptions)

You didn't specify the output "structure", but here's one method you could use which outputs a nested array - first level is chapters, in each chapter there's an array of lines

```
var xml = `<chapter>
<line /> Some text which I want to grab.
<line /> Some more text which I want to grab.
<line /> Even more text which I want to grab.
</chapter>`

var parser = new DOMParser();
var content = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml')
var chapters = content.getElementsByTagName('chapter');
var obj = [].reduce.call(chapters, function(result, chapter) {
    var lines = chapter.getElementsByTagName('line');
    result.push([].reduce.call(lines, function(result, line) {
        var text = '';
        for(var node = line.nextSibling; node && node.nodeType == 3; node = node.nextSibling) {
            text += node.nodeValue;
        }
        result.push(text);
        return result;
    }, []))
    return result;
}, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

> addressing the comments - firstly some documentation:

[DOMParse documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

[Array#reduce documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

[Function#call documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Now, to explain  `[].reduce.call(array, fn)` in this code

`[].reduce.call` is shorthand for `Array.prototype.reduce.call`

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `HTMLCollection` ... which behaves like an array, except it isn't one ... there are several ways to make an array out of a HTMLCollection - the most primitive:

```
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    array[i] = collection[i];
}
```

or

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(collection);
```

or (ES2015+) - not available in IE unless you polyfill - see documentation

```
var array = Array.from(collection);
```

However, using the `.call` method on `[].reduce` allows the first argument (the `this` argument) to be any iterable, not just an array, and so it's just like using `array` from above like `array.reduce(fn)` - it's a way to treat the HTMLcollection like an array, without the need for an intermediate variable

Comment: thank you so much! this looks amazing. - however, being a beginner, i personally can't follow 100% - could you tell me what DomParser is / what I would have to look for to find out more about it (I only seem to find php & java domparsing tutorials)? I am also a bit confused about what this does: `[].reduce.call` (esp this notation of `[]`)

Comment: I've added some documentation links and an overview